# Why would I implement methods on a trait instead of as part of the trait?

Tags: rust, traits

While trying to understand the `Any` trait better, I saw that it [has an `impl` block for the trait itself](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.31.1/src/libcore/any.rs#L146). I don't understand the purpose of this construct, or even if it has a specific name.

I made a little experiment with both a "normal" trait method and a method defined in the `impl` block:

```
trait Foo {
    fn foo_in_trait(&self) {
        println!("in foo")
    }
}

impl dyn Foo {
    fn foo_in_impl(&self) {
        println!("in impl")
    }
}

impl Foo for u8 {}

fn main() {
    let x = Box::new(42u8) as Box<dyn Foo>;
    x.foo_in_trait();
    x.foo_in_impl();

    let y = &42u8 as &dyn Foo;
    y.foo_in_trait();
    y.foo_in_impl(); // May cause an error, see below
}
```

> **Editor's note**
>
> In versions of Rust up to and including Rust 1.15.0, the line
>   `y.foo_in_impl()` causes the error:
>
> ```
> error: borrowed value does not live long enough
>   --> src/main.rs:20:14
>    |
> 20 |     let y = &42u8 as &Foo;
>    |              ^^^^ does not live long enough
> ...
> 23 | }
>    | - temporary value only lives until here
>    |
>    = note: borrowed value must be valid for the static lifetime...
> ```
>
> This error is no longer present in subsequent versions, but the
>   concepts explained in the answers are still valid.

From this limited experiment, it seems like methods defined in the `impl` block are more restrictive than methods defined in the `trait` block. It's likely that there's something extra that doing it this way unlocks, but I just don't know what it is yet! ^_^

The sections from *The Rust Programming Language* on [traits](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch10-02-traits.html) and [trait objects](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch17-02-trait-objects.html) don't make any mention of this. Searching the Rust source itself, it seems like only `Any` and [`Error`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/error/trait.Error.html) use this particular feature. I've not seen this used in the handful of crates where I have looked at the source code.

Comment: Very interesting question! `Self` in the trait block is `Foo` and `Self` in the `impl` block is `Foo + 'static` ...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

When you define a trait named `Foo` that can be made into an object, Rust also defines a trait object type named `dyn Foo`. In older versions of Rust, this type was only called `Foo` (see [What does "dyn" mean in a type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50650070/3650362)). For backwards compatibility with these older versions, `Foo` still works to name the trait object type, although `dyn` syntax should be used for new code.

Trait objects have a lifetime parameter that designates the shortest of the implementor's lifetime parameters. To specify that lifetime, you write the type as `dyn Foo + 'a`.

When you write `impl dyn Foo {` (or just `impl Foo {` using the old syntax), you are not specifying that lifetime parameter, and it defaults to `'static`. This note from the compiler on the `y.foo_in_impl();` statement hints at that:

> note: borrowed value must be valid for the static lifetime...

All we have to do to make this more permissive is to write a generic `impl` over any lifetime:

```
impl<'a> dyn Foo + 'a {
    fn foo_in_impl(&self) { println!("in impl") }
}
```

Now, notice that the `self` argument on `foo_in_impl` is a borrowed pointer, which has a lifetime parameter of its own. The type of `self`, in its full form, looks like `&'b (dyn Foo + 'a)` (the parentheses are required due to operator precedence). A `Box<u8>` owns its `u8` – it doesn't borrow anything –, so you can create a `&(dyn Foo + 'static)` out of it. On the other hand, `&42u8` creates a `&'b (dyn Foo + 'a)` where `'a` is not `'static`, because `42u8` is put in a hidden variable on the stack, and the trait object borrows this variable. (That doesn't really make sense, though; `u8` doesn't borrow anything, so its `Foo` implementation should always be compatible with `dyn Foo + 'static`... the fact that `42u8` is borrowed from the stack should affect `'b`, not `'a`.)

Another thing to note is that trait methods are polymorphic, even when they have a default implementation and they're not overridden, while inherent methods on a trait objects are monomorphic (there's only one function, no matter what's behind the trait). For example:

```
use std::any::type_name;

trait Foo {
    fn foo_in_trait(&self)
    where
        Self: 'static,
    {
        println!("{}", type_name::<Self>());
    }
}

impl dyn Foo {
    fn foo_in_impl(&self) {
        println!("{}", type_name::<Self>());
    }
}

impl Foo for u8 {}
impl Foo for u16 {}

fn main() {
    let x = Box::new(42u8) as Box<dyn Foo>;
    x.foo_in_trait();
    x.foo_in_impl();

    let x = Box::new(42u16) as Box<Foo>;
    x.foo_in_trait();
    x.foo_in_impl();
}
```

Sample output:

```
u8
dyn playground::Foo
u16
dyn playground::Foo
```

In the trait method, we get the type name of the underlying type (here, `u8` or `u16`), so we can conclude that the type of `&self` will vary from one implementer to the other (it'll be `&u8` for the `u8` implementer and `&u16` for the `u16` implementer – not a trait object). However, in the inherent method, we get the type name of `dyn Foo` (`+ 'static`), so we can conclude that the type of `&self` is always `&dyn Foo` (a trait object).

Answer (score 9):

I *suspect* that the reason is very simple: may be overridden or not?

A method implemented in a `trait` block can be overridden by implementors of the `trait`, it just provides a default.

On the other hand, a method implemented in an `impl` block cannot be overridden.

<strike>If this reasoning is right, then the error you get for `y.foo_in_impl()` is just a lack of polish: it should have worked.</strike> *See Francis Gagné's more complete answer on the interaction with lifetimes.*

Comment: Your answer is in a sense better. It answers the central part of the doubt up front.  The intricate details can follow, but the main idea is to be put upfront; the other answer does it reversed.