# How do I clone a HashMap containing a boxed trait object?

Tags: rust

I have `HashMap` with custom hasher. Items of this `HashMap` without implemented trait `Clone` (it's a trait), but there is function to clone items like this:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::hash::BuildHasherDefault;

use fnv::FnvHasher;

trait Item {
    fn get_id(&self) -> i32;
    fn cloned(&self) -> Box<Item>;
}

#[derive(Clone)]
struct ItemImpl {
    id: i32,
    foo: i32
}

impl Item for ItemImpl {
    fn get_id(&self) -> i32 { self.id }
    fn cloned(&self) -> Box<Item> { Box::new(self.clone()) }
}

fn main() {
    let hash_map = HashMap::<i32, Box<Item>, BuildHasherDefault<FnvHasher>>::default();
}
```

How I could clone `hash_map` shortly (in code) and efficiently (without creating a temporary collection)?

Comment: I don't think you can use a `HashMap::<i32, Item, …>` at all, the value should be a Sized type, but a trait is Unsized.

Comment: Can you just implement `Clone`?

Comment: It's not clear what this question is asking. Could you say more about what problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: @kennytm, It's my misstype. Should be Box<Item>

Comment: @ChrisEmerson, I wish, but it beaks [object safety](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/trait-objects.html#object-safety) and other parts of code

Comment: @BurntSushi5, I just wish clone specified HashMap, but I can't implement trait `Clone` for my trait `Item`, thus I can't use method `HashMap::clone()`

Comment: Can you use a wrapper struct here and implement `Clone` for that?

Comment: Yes, I can. But changing definition of `HashMap` just for cloning, it seems a bit strange to me. May be there is another solution without changing other code that work with this `HashMap`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can implement `Clone` for the boxed trait object itself:

```
impl Clone for Box<Item> {
    fn clone(&self) -> Self {
        self.cloned()
    }
}
```

Now you may clone the `HashMap`. Note that the custom hasher has nothing to do with the problem.

See also

- [Why would I implement methods on a trait instead of as part of the trait?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34438755/155423)