# No method found when extending the Iterator trait in Rust

Tags: rust

I am trying to extend the functionality of the `Iterator` trait.

My `statistics/iter_statistics.rs`:

```
mod iter_statistics {
    pub trait IterStatistics: Iterator<Item = f64> {
        fn foo(&mut self) -> f64 {
            0.0
        }
    }

    impl IterStatistics for Iterator<Item = f64> {}
}
```

And `statistics/mod.rs`:

```
pub use self::iter_statistics::*;
mod iter_statistics;
```

And finally in my test code I have

```
use statistics::IterStatistics;

fn main() {
    let z: Vec<f64> = vec![0.0, 3.0, -2.0];
    assert_eq!(z.into_iter().foo(), 0.0);
}
```

When I run the test, I get:

```
error: no method name `foo` found for type `std::vec::IntoIter<f64>` in the current scope
assert_eq!(z.into_iter().foo(), 0.0);
                         ^~~
```

which is strange to me since the [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.IntoIter.html) for `IntoIter<T>` say it implements `Iterator<Item=T>`.

Comment: It's a side point, but as described you have a module `iter_statistics::iter_statistics`, which probably isn't what you meant; no need for the `mod {}` inside the file named after it.

Comment: @ChrisEmerson Yup that was a redundancy from when I was formulating the sample code :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `impl` you have written will only apply to trait objects (e.g. `&mut Iterator<Item=f64>`), not for all types that implement `Iterator<Item=f64>`. You want to write a generic `impl` like this:

```
impl<T: Iterator<Item=f64>> IterStatistics for T {}
```

Comment: Related: [Why would I implement methods on a trait instead of as part of the trait?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/34438755/155423)

Answer (score 3):

Your implementation is backward. When programming in Rust, you have to forget about OO-inheritance and reason in terms of capabilities.

> What does `trait D: B` means in Rust?

This means that `D` can only be implemented for types that already implement `B`. It's not *inheritance*, it's a *constraint*.

> When to use `trait D: B` then?

The main reason to use this constraint is when you wish to provide a default implementation of `D` methods that will require associated items (traits, constants, methods) from `B`.

In general, you do not want to add more constraints than strictly necessary, as your clients may wish to use this trait in ways you did not foresee.

The one exception is when creating a trait as a "bundle of constraints", so that you do not have type `T: SomeTrait + SomeOtherTrait + Send` for all the methods your are implementing. This "bundle of constraints" should be empty, then; it's not a functional trait after all, just an "alias".

> So, how to extend `Iterator`?

First declare a new trait:

```
pub trait IterStatistics {
    fn foo(&mut self) -> f64;
}
```

Then implement it for all types already implementing `Iterator<Item = f64>`:

```
impl<T> IterStatistics for T
    where T: Iterator<Item = f64>
{
    fn foo(&mut self) -> f64 {
        0.0
    }
}
```