# Why can't a type which implements trait A which itself implements trait B be converted to a trait object of B?

Tags: rust, traits

I have a trait `Service` defined as follows:

```
trait Service {
    fn do_something(&self);
}
```

`Service` is implemented by another trait, `FancyService`:

```
trait FancyService {
    fn fancy(&self) -> i32;
    fn do_something_fancy(&self, t: i32);
}

impl Service for FancyService {
    fn do_something(&self) {
        let t = self.fancy();

        self.do_something_fancy(t);
    }
}
```

Finally I have a `struct` that implements `FancyService`:

```
struct MyFancyService {
    t: i32
}

impl FancyService for MyFancyService {
    fn fancy(&self) -> i32 { self.t }
    fn do_something_fancy(&self, t: i32) { println!("t: {}", t); }
}
```

The idea is `MyFancyService` should now also implement `Service` and thus I should be able to put it in a `Box<Service>`, like this:

```
let s: Box<Service> = Box::new(MyFancyService { t: 42 });
```

This doesn't compile. Rust complains that `MyFancyService`:

> ```
>    |
> 28 |     let s: Box<Service> = Box::new(MyFancyService { t: 42 });
>    |                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `Service` is not implemented for `MyFancyService`
>    |
>    = note: required for the cast to the object type `Service`
> ```

Given that `MyFancyService` implements `FancyService` which implements `Service`, why doesn't `MyFancyService` implement `Service`?

Sample code in the [playground](http://play.integer32.com/?gist=0fdb6b532607b0fe7e7bcb1ad24cdd8e&version=stable).

Comment: See also: [Why would I implement methods on a trait instead of as part of the trait?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34438755/155423)

Comment: I oversimplified my question into a duplicate. Is there a question that covers this case, but where `FancyService` and `MyFancyService` are generic?

Comment: Can you expand a bit more on what you mean by "generic" in this case? I don't know what it would mean to implement a "generic" trait for a "generic" type...

Comment: @Shepmaster. Thanks for asking, I was able to figure it out. I needed to use associated types instead of making my trait generic.

Comment: Ah, so the second answer on the linked duplicate then?

Comment: I don't remember what got me to look at associated types. But your question [When is it appropriate to use an associated type versus a generic type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32059370/when-is-it-appropriate-to-use-an-associated-type-versus-a-generic-type), and the associated answer helped me greatly in figuring out when to use what feature.