# How do I create a trait object from another trait object?

Tags: rust, trait-objects

The latest stable version of Rust (1.27) allows implementing a trait for trait objects (`dyn Trait`), so I tried the [following](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b17adb1d0d6f844498661b21eb0b7358&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015):

```
trait T1 {
    fn f1(&self);
}
trait T2 {
    fn f2(&self);
}
impl T2 for dyn T1 {
    fn f2(&self) {
        self.f1()
    }
}
struct S();
impl T1 for S {
    fn f1(&self) {}
}

fn main() {
    let t1 = S();
    let t12: &T1 = &t1;
    t12.f2();
    let t2: &T2 = &t12;
    t2.f2();
}
```

The above code results in an error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `&T1: T2` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:21:19
   |
21 |     let t2: &T2 = &t12;
   |                   -^^^
   |                   |
   |                   the trait `T2` is not implemented for `&T1`
   |                   help: consider removing 1 leading `&`-references
   |
   = help: the following implementations were found:
             <T1 + 'static as T2>
   = note: required for the cast to the object type `T2`
```

This is confusing as `&T1` is an instance of `dyn T1` and so has a `T2` implementation. We can even witness this by the fact that we can call `f2` on `t12` directly, as removing the last two lines in `main` makes it compile.

Is it possible to create a trait object from a trait object that marked as a different trait?

Comment: *The latest stable version of Rust (1.27) allows* — This has been allowed **since Rust 1.0**. The only thing that's new is the literal `dyn` keyword. Your code behaves the same without it (`impl T2 for T1 { /* ... */ }`).

Answer (score 3):

You are implementing `T2` for a trait object itself (`dyn T1`), but trying to use it for a *reference* to a trait object (`&dyn T1`).

Try `impl<'a> T2 for &'a dyn T1 { ... }` instead. This means "For any lifetime `'a`, implement `T2` for a reference that is valid for `'a` and refers to a `T1`-trait object".
I don't know any good use of `impl ... for dyn ...` itself.

[Adjusted code from the question in the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=9797c6d08f2f3eaa0c870a22fd82499e&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015)

Comment: [Why would I implement methods on a trait instead of as part of the trait?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34438755/155423); [When should I not implement a trait for references to implementors of that trait?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/28799372/155423).

Comment: There is of cause a use: as an "extended" trait of `T1` so we can call methods from `T2` rather than `T1`, like the way I wrote `t12.f2()`. But if this is the only reason we should use `impl<T> T2 for T where T: T1` instead...