# Define a method in trait returning a default implementation of Self

Tags: rust, traits

I would like to have the following functionality

```rust
trait Policy {
    fn eval(&self, k: u32) -> bool;

    fn default() -> Box<dyn Policy>
    where
        Self: Sized,
    {
        Box::new(MaxPolicy { max: 2 })
    }
}

struct MaxPolicy {
    max: u32,
}

impl Policy for MaxPolicy {
    fn eval(&self, k: u32) -> bool {
        println!("MaxPolicy");
        k < self.max
    }
}

#[test]
fn max_policy() {
    let p = MaxPolicy { max: 2 };
    assert!(!p.eval(3));
}

#[test]
fn default_policy() {
    let p = Policy::default();
    assert!(!p.eval(3));
}
```

([Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0e48521accf235a51ca8891a16b22195))

This does not compile:

```
error[E0283]: type annotations needed
  --> src/lib.rs:31:13
   |
4  |     fn default() -> Box<dyn Policy>
   |        -------
5  |     where
6  |         Self: Sized,
   |               ----- required by this bound in `Policy::default`
...
31 |     let p = Policy::default();
   |             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ cannot infer type
   |
   = note: cannot resolve `_: Policy`
```

Would it possible to alter the approach to make it work? Is this even possible for trait objects to have a method returning some implementation of `Self`? If not, why not?

Comment: Exactly _which_ type should `Policy::default()` return?

Comment: Any type implementing `Policy`, that is why it is `Box`-ed. Even if one puts there a concrete type, say, `MaxPolicy`, it will not compile (https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=03fd001b07747366ac4d480613a650c5)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement `default` on the trait object type, not on the trait:

```
trait Policy {
    fn eval(&self, k: u32) -> bool;
}

impl dyn Policy {
    fn default() -> Box<Self> {
        Box::new(MaxPolicy { max: 2 })
    }
}
```

See also:

- [Why would I implement methods on a trait instead of as part of the trait?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34438755/155423)

Comment: wow, I was not familiar with this syntax, much more concise, than my approach with `enum`-s

Comment: FYI, if you want to add markers to what `default()` returns, you need to explicitly write the trait name, e.g., `fn default() -> Box<dyn Policy + Send>`

Answer (score 0):

I constructed a workaround which has a similar nice API

```rust
trait Policy {
    fn eval(&self, k: u32) -> bool;
}

struct MaxPolicy {
    max: u32,
}

impl Policy for MaxPolicy {
    fn eval(&self, k: u32) -> bool {
        println!("MaxPolicy");
        k < self.max
    }
}

struct MinPolicy {
    min: u32,
}

impl Policy for MinPolicy {
    fn eval(&self, k: u32) -> bool {
        println!("MinPolicy");
        k > self.min
    }
}

enum PolicyEnum {
    Custom(Box<dyn Policy>),
    Default,
}

impl PolicyEnum {
    const DEFAULT: MaxPolicy = MaxPolicy { max: 4 };
}

impl Policy for PolicyEnum {
    fn eval(&self, k: u32) -> bool {
        match self {
            PolicyEnum::Custom(p) => p.eval(k),
            PolicyEnum::Default => Self::DEFAULT.eval(k),
        }
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b1c938f10311bfa5fa9a71704f5da0dc)

With that, it's possible to do:

```rust
#[test]
fn default() {
    let p = PolicyEnum::Default;

    assert!(p.eval(3));
}

#[test]
fn custom() {
    let p = PolicyEnum::Custom(Box::new(MinPolicy{min: 4}));

    assert!(p.eval(5));
}
```