# How do I use a trait object in a BinaryHeap?

Tags: oop, rust, traits, trait-objects

I have the following simplified code:

```
use std::collections::BinaryHeap;
use std::rc::Rc;

struct JobId;
struct Coord;
struct TimeStep;

pub trait HasJob {
    fn id(&self) -> JobId;
    fn start(&self) -> Coord;
    fn end(&self) -> Coord;
    fn earliest_start(&self) -> TimeStep;
    fn latest_finish(&self) -> TimeStep;
}

type JobPtr = Rc<HasJob>;

// a concrete class that implements the above trait
// and other basic traits like Eq, Hash, Ord, etc
pub struct Job {}
// another class that implements the HasJob trait
pub struct JobPrime {}

fn main() {
    // this line raises a compiler error
    let heap: BinaryHeap<JobPtr> = BinaryHeap::with_capacity(10);
}
```

The basic idea is to use the (unique) `id`s for ordering.

The heap initialization causes the following error:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `HasJob: std::cmp::Ord` is not satisfied
  --> src/main.rs:24:36
   |
24 |     let heap: BinaryHeap<JobPtr> = BinaryHeap::with_capacity(10);
   |                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::cmp::Ord` is not implemented for `HasJob`
   |
   = note: required because of the requirements on the impl of `std::cmp::Ord` for `std::rc::Rc<HasJob>`
   = note: required by `<std::collections::BinaryHeap<T>>::with_capacity`
```

I've just started trying my hand at Rust and have an OOP/C++/Java background. The intention is to use the `HasJob` trait as an "interface" and use that to induce type erasure/dynamic dispatch w.r.t generic collections/containers - A common OOP pattern.

If I understand correctly, the generic parameter of `BinaryHeap` has the constraint that the concrete type passed to it needs to implement the `Ord` trait. Attempting to extend the original trait with required trait like so...

```
pub trait HasJob: Ord + /*others*/
```

... violates Rust's object safety guarantee and raises this compiler error:

```
error[E0038]: the trait `HasJob` cannot be made into an object
  --> src/main.rs:16:22
   |
16 |     type JobPtr = Rc<HasJob>;
   |                      ^^^^^^ the trait `HasJob` cannot be made into an object
   |
   = note: the trait cannot use `Self` as a type parameter in the supertraits or where-clauses
```

How do I get around the above issue?

Comment: You might wish to state whether the elements in the binary heap really need to be trait objects, and/or reference-counted. What concrete implementations of `HasJob` do you have?

Comment: How do you impose an ordering on `JobPtr`s, using only `id`, `start`, `end`, `earliest_start`, and `latest_finish`?

Comment: Basically the same as [How to test for equality between trait objects](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25339603/155423)

Comment: @E_net4 There is just one concrete impl. of HasJob and it merely returns the values of the corresponding fields. The example code I've posted above is just a toy example I've been using to understand how Rust works.  The job objects are shared elsewhere, which is why I've used a ref-counted pointer. For what it's worth, using a regular reference causes the same errors.

Comment: You seem to have exposed an XY problem. :) With only one concrete implementation, you don't need to use trait objects.

Comment: @trentcl The code is largely a toy example, but the basic idea is to use the (unique) ids for ordering.

Comment: @E_net4 Indeed - I do realize that. The point of the exercise was, however, to write the code based on the assumption that there are multiple implementations. As I mentioned before, the code only serves to help me understand how the language works.

Comment: @Shepmaster Apologies, but I don't see how that post relates to my question. Could please clarify?

Comment: @shadeMe [Shepmaster's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49138717/3650362) to the other post applied to your problem: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=f5d899182c7b65145f9de8020c22c4c8&version=stable). To compare `HasJob` trait objects, you have to implement `Ord` *for `HasJob`*, not just for a type that implements `HasJob` (because it isn't possible to compare different types even if they both implement `Ord`.)

Comment: @trentcl Ah, I just noticed that he has added his own answer for trait objects. I didn't realize one could implement super traits for traits that way. Marked as duplicate, thanks!