# Default trait method implementation for all trait objects

Tags: types, rust, traits, default-implementation, trait-objects

I have a trait `MyTrait`, and I want all trait objects `&dyn MyTrait` to be comparable to each other and to nothing else. I have that now based on [How to test for equality between trait objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339603/how-to-test-for-equality-between-trait-objects).

The problem is that I need to use `MyTraitComparable` everywhere, instead of `MyTrait`. Is there a way to get around this?

```
use std::any::Any;

trait MyTrait {}

trait MyTraitComparable: MyTrait {
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any;

    fn equals(&self, other: &dyn MyTraitComparable) -> bool;
}

impl<S: 'static + MyTrait + PartialEq> MyTraitComparable for S {
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any {
        self as &dyn Any
    }

    fn equals(&self, other: &dyn MyTraitComparable) -> bool {
        match other.as_any().downcast_ref::<S>() {
            None => false,
            Some(a) => self == a,
        }
    }
}

#[derive(PartialEq)]
struct MyObj {
    a: i32,
}
impl MyObj {
    fn new(a: i32) -> MyObj {
        MyObj { a }
    }
}

impl MyTrait for MyObj {}

fn main() {
    assert!(as_trait_obj_and_compare(&MyObj::new(1), &MyObj::new(1)));
}

fn as_trait_obj_and_compare(obj: &dyn MyTraitComparable, another_obj: &dyn MyTraitComparable) -> bool {
    obj.equals(another_obj)
}
```

I tried moving `as_any` and `equals` to `MyTrait` and providing a default implementation, but

- I don't think I can use `self` in that case, so it doesn't work.
- If I use `trait MyTrait: PartialEq` then I can't create trait objects anymore.

Comment: Thinking out of the box, rename `MyTrait` to `MyTraitBase` and `MyTraitComparable` to `MyTrait` — voilà: you are using `MyTrait` everywhere.

Comment: @Shepmaster perhaps an improvement, thanks, but not quite everywhere since all the structs must implement ``MyTraitBase``.

Answer (score 2):

If you're willing to use a nightly compiler and unstable features, you can use [specialization](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1210-impl-specialization.md) to avoid having two traits:

```
#![feature(specialization)]

use std::any::Any;

trait MyTrait {
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any;
    fn equals(&self, other: &dyn MyTrait) -> bool;
}

default impl<S: 'static + PartialEq> MyTrait for S {
    default fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any {
        self as &dyn Any
    }

    default fn equals(&self, other: &dyn MyTrait) -> bool {
        match other.as_any().downcast_ref::<S>() {
            None => false,
            Some(a) => self == a,
        }
    }
}

#[derive(PartialEq)]
struct MyObj {
    a: i32,
}
impl MyObj {
    fn new(a: i32) -> MyObj {
        MyObj { a }
    }
}

impl MyTrait for MyObj {}

fn main() {
    assert!(as_trait_obj_and_compare(&MyObj::new(1), &MyObj::new(1)));
}

fn as_trait_obj_and_compare(obj: &dyn MyTrait, another_obj: &dyn MyTrait) -> bool {
    obj.equals(another_obj)
}
```

Comment: Although I don't use nightly, it's good to know there is a solution under consideration!