# How can I create hashable trait objects / trait objects with generic method parameters?

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I have some structs that implement both `Hash` and `MyTrait`. I'm using them as `&dyn MyTrait` trait objects.

Now I want `&dyn MyTrait` to also implement `Hash`. I've tried a few things:

- Naively, `trait MyTrait: Hash {}`:

  ```
  the trait `MyTrait` cannot be made into an object
  ```
- Then I tried this:

  ```
  impl Hash for dyn MyTrait {
      fn hash<H: Hasher>(&self, hasher: &mut H) {
          // ...
      }
  }
  ```

  but I need to delegate to the `hash` method of the concrete type of `self`, I think.
- So the naive next step is to put this on `MyTrait`:

  ```
  fn my_hash<H: Hasher>(&self, hasher: &mut H);
  ```

  which brings me right back to the first point.
- I read something about using a trait object instead of generic parameter, which sounds smart, so I put this on `MyTrait`

  ```
  fn my_hash(&self, hasher: &mut H);
  ```

  Then I need to actually implement this. Preferably not by hand for every trait:

  ```
  impl<T: 'static + Hash> MyTrait for T {
      fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any {
          self as &dyn Any
      }

      fn my_hash(&self, hasher: &mut Hasher) {
          self.as_any().downcast_ref::<T>().unwrap().hash(hasher)
      }
  }
  ```

  but then

  ```
  the trait bound `std::hash::Hasher: std::marker::Sized` is not satisfied
  `std::hash::Hasher` does not have a constant size known at compile-time
  ```

  So I'd have to downcast `Hasher`…
- If downcasting `Hasher` is the way, I need a generic parameter `H` that can convert to an `Any` `Hasher`, Let's try:

  ```
  trait AnyHasher {
      fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any;
  }

  impl<H: 'static + Hasher> AnyHasher for H {
      fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any {
          self as &dyn Any
      }
  }
  ```

  and then to downcast

  ```
  impl<T: 'static + Hash, H: 'static + Hasher> MyTrait for T {
      // ...
      fn my_hash(&self, hasher: &mut AnyHasher) {
          let h = hasher.as_any().downcast_ref::<H>().unwrap();
          self.as_any().downcast_ref::<T>().unwrap().hash(h)
      }
  }
  ```

  but alas

  ```
  the type parameter `H` is not constrained by the impl trait, self type, or predicates
  ```

  which I guess is true, but then I'm stuck. (Also it seems kind of ridiculous so far).

Can this can be done? If so, how?

I previously asked about [`PartialEq` for trait objects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49466199/default-trait-method-implementation-for-all-trait-objects), which was hard because information the concrete type of the trait object is needed. That was solved with downcasting, but I didn't manage to apply that solution here.

Comment: Your first example [works for me](https://play.integer32.com/?gist=8926ba000a1b5a1ca48c659078af7b69&version=stable)

Comment: @Jmb True, but it's not possible to make objects of that trait: https://play.integer32.com/?gist=066b22be8dc9286bf88f7da709d095ff&version=stable (or I don't know how)

Comment: I am stuck on almost the same case as this, did you already solved it?

Comment: Why don't you add a `hash` method in your trait that you call in your second try?

Comment: @Boiethios Ah yes you're right, it was kind of preparing for the next step (using trait object `&Hasher`) which needs a new method name. But it doesn't make sense that I changed the name one step early, sorry.

Comment: @Mark I'm writing a POC

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm not a Rust expert, but it seems to me that you try to turn Rust into Java (don't be offended: I really do like Java).

> How can I create hashable trait objects?

You don't want to create a hashtable of trait objects (it's easy), you want to create a hashtable of traits that *are not* trait objects and that's why you encounter difficulties.

## The problem

I summarize: you have some various structs that implement traits `MyTrait`, `Hash` and `Eq`, and you would like to put those mixed structs into a single a hashtable as a `TunedMyTrait` trait objects. This requires
`TunedMyTrait` to be a subtrait of `Hash` and `Eq`. But whereas `MyTrait` can be made a trait object, *`TunedMyTrait` cannot*.

I'm sure you know why, but I will try to make it clear for other readers, using [this valuable resource](https://github.com/brson/rust-anthology/blob/master/src/all-about-trait-objects.md). (I put it in my own words, don't be shy and edit it if you think that isn't clear.) Trait objects rely on something that is called "object safety" (see [the RFC 255](https://github.com/nox/rust-rfcs/blob/master/text/0255-object-safety.md)). "Object safety" means: all methods of the trait must be object-safe.

Rust makes an intensive usage of the stack, thus it has to know the size of everything it can. After the borrow checker, that's one of the difficulties and the beauties of Rust. A trait object is typed and sized: it is some kind of "fat" pointer that contains information on the concrete type. Every method call is delegated to the concrete type, using a `vtable` of methods. I don't get into details, but some issues may occur with this delegation and the "safety check" was created to avoid those issues. Here:

- the method `fn eq(&self, other: &Rhs) -> bool` where `Rhs = Self` is not object safe, because at runtime, `Rhs` was erased, and thus the concrete type and the size of `other` is not known.
- the method `fn hash<H: Hasher>(&self, hasher: &mut H)` is not object safe, because the `vtable` is not built for every concrete type `H`.

## The solution

Okay. `MyTrait` is a trait object, but `TunedMyTrait` is not. Yet only `TunedMyTrait` objects may be valid keys for your hashtable. What can you do?

You can try, as you did, to hack the object safety mechanism. You found a solution to hack `PartialEq` (with a cast try, [How to test for equality between trait objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339603/how-to-test-for-equality-between-trait-objects)), and you have now another hack from @Boiethios (which basically makes of hash a non generic function). If you finally reach your goal, I can imagine the future reader of the code: "OMG, what is this guy trying to do?" or (worse): "I'm not sure of what it does, but I'm pretty sure it would run faster if...". You have hacked a protection of the language and your code is likely to create issues worse than the problem you are trying to solve. This reminds me this kind of discussion: [Get generic type of class at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3403909/get-generic-type-of-class-at-runtime). And then? What will you do with this piece of code?

Or you can be reasonable. There are some possibilities: you use a hashtable with keys that are really of the same concrete type, you box your `MyTrait` objects, you use an enum... There may be other ways (as said, I'm not a Rust expert).

Don't get me wrong: hacking a language is really fun and helps to understand deeply its mechanics and limits (note: if you hadn't asked that question, I wouldn't have had a close look at DST and trait objects, thus I thank you). But you have to be serious if you intend to do something serious: Rust is not Java...

**EDIT**

> I want to compare and hash objects that are runtime-polymorphic.

That's not difficult, but you also want to put them in a `HashMap`, and that is the problem.

I will give you another insight. Basically, you know that a hashtable is an array of buckets. Rust uses open addressing to resolve hash collisions (specifically: Robin Hood hashing), that means that every bucket will contain 0 or 1 pair `(key, value)`. When you [put a pair `(key, value)` in an empty bucket](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/libstd/collections/hash/table.rs#L476), the tuple `(key, value)` is written in the buffer array, at the position [`pair_start + index * sizeof::<K, V>()`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/master/src/libstd/collections/hash/table.rs#L242), according to [the definition of `offset`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.22.0/std/primitive.pointer.html). It's obvious that you need *sized* pairs.

If you could use trait object, you would have fat pointer, which is sized. But that's not possible for the reasons already stated. All the ideas I proposed are focused on this: have sized keys (assuming that values are already sized). Concrete type: obviously sized. Boxing: size of a pointer. Enum: size of the biggest element + size of the tag + padding.

## Basic example with boxing

*WARNING: I tried hard to find an example on the internet, but didn't find anything. So I decided to create from scratch a basic example with boxing, but I'm not sure this is the right way to do it. Please comment or edit if needed.*

First, add to your trait a method that identifies every instance of any concrete type that implements `MyTrait` with a **comparable** and **hashable** value, let's say an `id` method that returns an `i64`:

```
trait MyTrait {
    fn id(&self) -> i64; // any comparable and hashable type works instead of i64
}
```

`Foo` and `Bar` concrete types will implement this method (the implementation given here is totally stupid):

```
struct Foo(u32);

impl MyTrait for Foo {
    fn id(&self) -> i64 {
        -(self.0 as i64)-1 // negative to avoid collisions with Bar
    }
}

struct Bar(String);

impl MyTrait for Bar {
    fn id(&self) -> i64 {
        self.0.len() as i64 // positive to avoid collisions with Foo
    }
}
```

Now, we have to implement `Hash` and `Eq`, in order to put `dyn MyTrait` in a `HashMap`. But if we do it for `dyn MyTrait`, we get a trait that can't be a trait object, because `dyn MyTrait` is not sized. Let's implement it for `Box<dyn Trait>`, which is sized:

```
impl Hash for Box<dyn MyTrait> {
    fn hash<H>(&self, state: &mut H) where H: Hasher {
        self.id().hash(state)
    }
}

impl PartialEq for Box<dyn MyTrait> {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Box<dyn MyTrait>) -> bool {
        self.id() == other.id()
    }
}

impl Eq for Box<dyn MyTrait> {}
```

We used the `id` method to implement `eq` and `hash`.

Now, think of `Box<dyn MyTrait>`: 1. it is sized; 2. it implements `Hash` and `Eq`. That means that it can be used as a key for a `HashMap`:

```
fn main() {
    let foo = Foo(42);
    let bar = Bar("answer".into());
    let mut my_map = HashMap::<Box<dyn MyTrait>, i32>::new();
    my_map.insert(Box::new(foo), 1);
    my_map.insert(Box::new(bar), 2);

    println!("{:?}", my_map.get(&(Box::new(Foo(42)) as Box<dyn MyTrait>)));
    println!("{:?}", my_map.get(&(Box::new(Foo(41)) as Box<dyn MyTrait>)));
    println!("{:?}", my_map.get(&(Box::new(Bar("answer".into())) as Box<dyn MyTrait>)));
    println!("{:?}", my_map.get(&(Box::new(Bar("question".into())) as Box<dyn MyTrait>)));
}
```

Output:

```
Some(1)
None
Some(2)
None
```

try it: https://play.integer32.com/?gist=85edc6a92dd50bfacf2775c24359cd38&version=stable

I'm not sure it solves your problem, but I don't really know what you are trying to do...

Comment: The summary is correct, except that the distinction between `TunedMyTrait` and `MyTrait` is an implementation thing; if they can be the same that'd be even better. As for Java, yeah it's probably based on various langauges that build vtables in jit or at runtime. But I think the problem is reasonable (solution probably isn't): I want to compare and hash objects that are runtime-polymorphic. Aren't trait objects the only runtime polymorphism? It surprises me that this problem doesn't come up more often.

Comment: The enum idea is creative, I like it. But it is more restricted, it only works for closed groups of objects.

Comment: The id is also a creative solution, thanks. Of course a totally unique id is even harder than a hash, so it sort of moves the problem. But when applicable, the code is much simpler this way.

Comment: Example for enum: https://play.integer32.com/?gist=fb6126ff415526fb8ba4fcc471014941&version=stable

Comment: @Mark The example for enum is really cool. Concerning the unique `id`: my feeling is that if you cannot produce a correct `id`, the objects should not go in the same `HashMap` or `HashSet`. That said, if you want a totally unique `id`, go with something like `format!("{:p}", &foo))` (the adress as a String). But if a `Foo` may be equal to another `Foo`, or even to a `Bar`, you have to consider the main attributes of the trait. In your example, I would take a tuple `(u64, String)`: `(0, a.to_text())` for `Alpha`s and `(1, b.to_text())` for `Beta`s.

Comment: It was hard to choose between the answers, but I'll go with this one for the various creative ideas, and because I can't get the other one to work.

Answer (score 1):

You can put the desired functionalities in your trait, *i.e.* you mix your second and third attempts:

```
use std::hash::{Hash, Hasher};
use std::collections::hash_map::DefaultHasher;
use std::collections::HashSet;

#[derive(Hash)]
struct Foo(i32);

#[derive(Hash)]
struct Bar(String);

// Put the desired functionalities in your trait

trait MyTrait {
    fn my_hash(&self, h: &mut dyn Hasher);
    fn my_eq(&self, other: &dyn MyTrait) -> bool {
        let mut hasher1 = DefaultHasher::new();
        let mut hasher2 = DefaultHasher::new();

        self.my_hash(&mut hasher1);
        other.my_hash(&mut hasher2);
        hasher1.finish() == hasher2.finish()
    }

    // other funcs
}

impl MyTrait for Foo {
    fn my_hash(&self, mut h: &mut dyn Hasher) {
        self.hash(&mut h);
    }
}

impl MyTrait for Bar {
    fn my_hash(&self, mut h: &mut dyn Hasher) {
        self.hash(&mut h);
    }
}

// Implement needed traits for your trait

impl Hash for dyn MyTrait {
    fn hash<H: Hasher>(&self, hasher: &mut H) {
        self.my_hash(hasher);
    }
}

impl PartialEq for dyn MyTrait {
    fn eq(&self, other: &dyn MyTrait) -> bool {
        self.my_eq(other)
    }
}

impl Eq for dyn MyTrait {}

// This compiles

fn main() {
    let foo = Foo(42);
    let bar = Bar("answer".into());
    let mut set = HashSet::new();

    set.insert(&foo as &dyn MyTrait);
    set.insert(&bar);
}
```

In my opinion, this is not a good thing to implement `Hash` for a trait in your way, because you do not know what is the concrete type beside the trait. Someone could implement the trait for both the same type, like:

```
struct Foo(String);
struct Bar(String);
```

In this case, how do you want to handle `Foo("hello")` vs `Bar("hello")`? Are they the same item? Because they will have the same hash.

The real question, in your case, is: *how do you define what is same or not from a trait?* In my opinion, a better way to handle this is to calculate the hash from "business" trait methods, for example:

```
#[derive(Hash)]
struct Baz(...); // Business item
#[derive(Hash)]
struct Qux(...); // Another business item

trait MyTrait {
    // all those returned items make my MyTrait unique
    fn description(&self) -> &str;
    fn get_baz(&self) -> Baz;
    fn get_qux(&self) -> Qux;
}

impl Hash for dyn MyTrait {
    fn hash<H: Hasher>(&self, hasher: &mut H) {
        self.description().hash(hasher);
        self.get_baz().hash(hasher);
        self.get_qux().hash(hasher);
    }
}
```

A trait is only a contract or a partial consideration of a thing (just like when you say that a "human being" is a "developer"). You should not (in my humble opinion) consider a trait as a concrete type.

Comment: Ow yeah that's pretty smart, I feel silly for not thinking of just returning the struct's hash! However...

Comment: I do wish I could use the same `Hasher`, a little bit for performance (this way I'd just delegate to the struct's `hash` method), but mostly because it seems the `Hasher` is passed for a reason (although I'm not too clear on how `Hasher`s differ).

Comment: (This is what I mean: https://play.integer32.com/?gist=745649a956638fb9fbeed0aa2420eb07&version=stable) - don't get me wrong though, the answer is smart and works for most practical cases; if nothing even better appears I'll accept it

Comment: @Mark: Do you mean reusing the same `Hasher` instance across multiple objects?

Comment: @MatthieuM. Ideally the same instance, but the same type would already be an improvement.

Comment: @MatthieuM. It's good that you raise the problem with hash collisions. In my case, I'll just accept the hash collision (my `eq` is not based on `hash`). It may be a performance problem but should work fine otherwise, right?

Comment: Thanks for the update, I like it, I think it's an improvement. I'm surprised, I thought it's not possible to go from trait object method (`my_hash`) to generic (`hash`) since trait object type is dynamic and generic type is static. I'll look into that.

Comment: @Mark: My point was more than an instance of `Hasher` should only be used for 1 (complete) object. The flow is (1) initialize the `Hasher`, (2) hash the fields and (3) finalize the `Hasher`. There is no provision from starting again from there; so a fresh new instance of `Hasher` needs be created for the next object. Each time. This is why `HashMap` takes a `HashBuilder` generic parameter.

Comment: @Mark About your last comment, this is kinda hack that permits this. You should test it because I'm not 100% sure it works (I crated a `&mut &mut H`)

Comment: I tried to verify the hash works by calculating it explicitly, but don't know how to get it to work :-( https://play.integer32.com/?gist=3e692d9b1b4a6a91cb81ae14fb4d13d3&version=stable