# How to match a string to generic function type parameters?

Tags: generics, rust

I need to call a generic method in the content of a `String` which is coming from a FFI caller, not from a static `&str` in the code:

```
match endpoint.as_ref() {
    "documents" => get_objs_as_json::<Document, JsonDocument>(db_url, sql),
    "theme_links" => get_objs_as_json::<ThemeLink, JsonThemeLink>(db_url, sql),
    "dressing_links" => get_objs_as_json::<DressingLink, JsonDressingLink>(db_url, sql),
    "dressing_configurations" => {
        get_objs_as_json::<DressingConfiguration, JsonDressingConfiguration>(db_url, sql)
    }
    &_ => Err(BackendError::InvalidArgument(endpoint)),
}
```

It's working, but really ugly, and I need to do this for each generic methods I have…

I tried to make an hashmap like `endpoint => (InputStruct, OutputStruct)` but I can't store and use the types like that.

Perhaps I can do that with a macro, but I don't know how to convert the string parameter into types in the macro.

**EDIT**
Ok, trying to reformulate.
I have a generic method who get data in my database from on struct type, then convert it to some other struct. But my caller doesn't know the name of the structs, so I need a wrapper to convert an arbitrary string to a couple of types.
The idea here is to replace (as in a C macro, even if I know that Rust macros  are different)

```
get_and_convert("documents", params)
```

by

```
get_and_convert<Document, JsonDocument>(params)
```

That because the "documents"  parameter come from FFI, the caller don't know the rust internal and can't call the generic method.

as in :

```
pub struct Document {
    pub a: i32,
}

pub struct JsonDocument {
    pub a: i32,
}

impl JsonDocument {
    pub fn to_json(&self) -> String {
        // …
    }
}

impl From<Document> for JsonDocument {
    fn from(input: Input) -> Self {
        Output {
            a: input.a
        }
    }
}

pub fn get_and_convert<I, O>(db_params: String) -> String {
    let input = get_data(db_params);
    let output = input.into();
    output.to_json()
}
```

So I tried something like that (I'm new to macros so the code is very wrong, read it more like a pseudo-code) :

```
macro_rules! get_types {
    ("documents") => {
        (Document, JsonDocument)
    };
    ("themes") => {
        (Theme, JsonTheme)
    };
}

macro_rules! get_objs {
    ($x:expr, $y:expr, $params:expr) => {
        get_and_convert::<$x, $y>($params)
    };
}
```

used like :

```
pub fn testmacro(args: String) {
    let (input_type, output_type) = get_types!("documents");
    let result = get_objs!(input_type, output_type, args);
}
```

Comment: What is `get_objs_as_json`? Writing a [mcve] will make it easier for someone to answer your question.

Comment: You can store hastable of traits like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49711479/how-can-i-create-hashable-trait-objects-trait-objects-with-generic-method-para) if that is what you need