# How do I create a HashMap with type erased keys?

Tags: rust, hashmap

I want to be able to use a variety of different types as keys in a `HashMap`, all of which would implement `Hash`. This seems like it should be possible: from reading the docs it seems that every `Hasher` will produce a `u64` result, so they eventually get reduced down to a common type. Effectively I want to do:

```rust
use std::{collections::HashMap, hash::Hash};

fn x(_: HashMap<Box<dyn Hash>, ()>) {}
```

which I'm not allowed to do:

```
error[E0038]: the trait `std::hash::Hash` cannot be made into an object
   --> src/lib.rs:3:9
    |
3   | fn x(_: HashMap<Box<dyn Hash>, ()>) {}
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `std::hash::Hash` cannot be made into an object
```

It seems like I *could* create a `Hasher` (e.g. `RandomState`), use that to manually calculate hash values, then store the `u64` result in a `HashMap<u64, _>` but that seems kind of overly complex. I don't ever want to get the key values back out again, I just need to be able to compare the hash values. Is there a `HashMap` alternative I'm not aware of? Or am I looking at this in a totally wrong way?

Comment: Your question might be answered by the answers of [How can I create hashable trait objects / trait objects with generic method parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49711479/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: Hash tables don't just work on hash values, they also need original objects for comparisons in case two values produce the same hash, which is both possible and allowed. To keep different objects in a hash table, you'd need to define a way to _compare_ values of different types.

Comment: See also [How to test for equality between trait objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25339603/155423)

Answer (score 8):

> It seems like I could create a `Hasher` (e.g. `RandomState`), use that to manually calculate hash values, then store the `u64` result in a `HashMap<u64, _>` but that seems kind of overly complex.

Unfortunately that's overly *simple* - since a hash function discards some information, hash tables don't just work on hashes, they also need the original key to compare it with the key you're inserting or looking for. This is necessary to handle the case when two keys produce the same hash, which is both possible and allowed.

Having said that, you *can* implement Python-style hash tables with heterogeneous keys in Rust, but you'll need to *box* the keys, i.e. use `Box<dyn Key>` as the type-erased key, with `Key` being a trait you define for all concrete types you want to use as the hash key. In particular, you'll need to:

- define the `Key` trait that specifies how to compare and hash the actual keys;
- (optionally) provide a blanket implementation of that trait for types that are themselves `Hash` and `Eq` so the user doesn't need to do that for every type manually;
- define `Eq` and `Hash` for `Box<dyn Key>` using the methods the trait provides, making `Box<dyn Key>` usable as key in `std::collections::HashMap`.

The `Key` trait could be defined like this:

```
trait Key {
    fn eq(&self, other: &dyn Key) -> bool;
    fn hash(&self) -> u64;
    // see https://stackoverflow.com/a/33687996/1600898
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any;
}
```

And here is a blanket implementation of `Key` for any type that is `Eq` and `Hash`:

```
use std::any::{Any, TypeId};
use std::collections::{HashMap, hash_map::DefaultHasher};
use std::hash::{Hash, Hasher};

impl<T: Eq + Hash + 'static> Key for T {
    fn eq(&self, other: &dyn Key) -> bool {
        if let Some(other) = other.as_any().downcast_ref::<T>() {
            return self == other;
        }
        false
    }

    fn hash(&self) -> u64 {
        let mut h = DefaultHasher::new();
        // mix the typeid of T into the hash to make distinct types
        // provide distinct hashes
        Hash::hash(&(TypeId::of::<T>(), self), &mut h);
        h.finish()
    }

    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any {
        self
    }
}
```

Finally, these impls will make `Box<dyn Key>` usable as hash table keys:

```
impl PartialEq for Box<dyn Key> {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        Key::eq(self.as_ref(), other.as_ref())
    }
}

impl Eq for Box<dyn Key> {}

impl Hash for Box<dyn Key> {
    fn hash<H: Hasher>(&self, state: &mut H) {
        let key_hash = Key::hash(self.as_ref());
        state.write_u64(key_hash);
    }
}

// just a convenience function to box the key
fn into_key(key: impl Eq + Hash + 'static) -> Box<dyn Key> {
    Box::new(key)
}
```

With all that in place, you can use the keys almost as you would in a dynamic language:

```
fn main() {
    let mut map = HashMap::new();
    map.insert(into_key(1u32), 10);
    map.insert(into_key("foo"), 20);
    map.insert(into_key("bar".to_string()), 30);
    assert_eq!(map.get(&into_key(1u32)), Some(&10));
    assert_eq!(map.get(&into_key("foo")), Some(&20));
    assert_eq!(map.get(&into_key("bar".to_string())), Some(&30));
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9af10da7b900fc5c9e6d75a9ae0d5a35)

Note that this implementation will always consider values of distinct concrete types to have different values. While Python's dictionaries will consider keys `1` and `1.0` to be the same key (while `"1"` will be distinct), an `into_key(1u32)` will be distinct not just from `into_key(1.0)`, but also from `into_key(1u64)`. Likewise, `into_key("foo")` will be a distinct from `into_key("foo".to_string())`. This could be changed by manually implementing `Key` for the types you care about, in which case the blanket implementation must be removed.

Answer (score -1):

I could not understand if you need to compare 2 hash or insert a hash into a HashMap, so i'm going to give you aswears to both.

This generic function generate hash for any given type.

```
fn hash<T>(obj: T) -> u64
where
    T: Hash,
{
    let mut hasher = DefaultHasher::new();
    obj.hash(&mut hasher);
    hasher.finish()
}
```

To compare you would do something like this :

```
let string = String::from("hello");
let _i32 = 12;

let result = hash(&string) == hash(_i32);

println!("{} == {} -> {}", &string, _i32, result);
```

This also work for struct  :

```
#[derive(Hash, Debug)]
struct Person{
    name : String,
    age : i32
}

let person1 = Person{name : "Kelvin".to_string(), age:  19};
let person2 = Person{name : "Dmitri".to_string(), age:  17};

let result = hash(&person1) == hash(&person2);

println!("{:?} == {:?} -> {}", &person1, &person2, result);
```

To insert Hash into a HashMap :

```
let mut HashMap : HashMap<u64, ()>  = HashMap::new();
HashMap.insert(hash("hello world"), ());
```