# Returning traits with dyn

Tags: rust

I've been trying to get this code to compile

```
pub trait Packet: PacketSerializer + ProtocolToID + Default {
    fn serialize_with_id(&self, ver: &ProtocolVersion) -> Box<ByteBuf>;
    fn deserialize_gen(buf: &mut ByteBuf) -> Box<Self>;
}

impl<T: PacketSerializer + ProtocolToID + PacketHandler + Default> Packet for T
{
    fn serialize_with_id(&self, ver: &ProtocolVersion) -> Box<ByteBuf> {
        let mut buf = Box::new(ByteBuf::new());
        buf.write_var_int(self.resolve_id(ver));
        self.serialize(&mut buf, &ver);
        buf
    }

    fn deserialize_gen(buf: &mut ByteBuf) -> Box<T> {
        let mut p: T = Default::default();
        p.deserialize(buf);
        Box::new(p)
    }
}

pub fn invoke_packet_handler(id: i32, buf: &mut ByteBuf) -> Box<dyn Packet> {
    Box::new(clientbound::SetCompression { threshold: 256 })
}
```

specifically `invoke_packet_handler` is supposed to return a `Box<dyn Packet>`

According to the docs, this should work https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/trait/dyn.html if you "statically" define the trait so the compiler can see it.

I get the following error at runtime

```
error[E0038]: the trait `Packet` cannot be made into an object
  --> src/serialize/packet.rs:43:61
   |
43 | pub fn invoke_packet_handler(id: i32, buf: &mut ByteBuf) -> Box<dyn Packet> {
   |                                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ `Packet` cannot be made into an object
```

I'm assuming this is because of the implementation for `Packet`? It's generic on every type that implements `PacketSerializer`, `ProtocolToID`, `PacketHandler` and `Default`

However,

```
pub fn invoke_packet_handler(id: i32, buf: &mut ByteBuf) -> Box<dyn PacketHandler> {
    Box::new(clientbound::SetCompression { threshold: 256 })
}
```

does compile if I specify a single trait

Comment: Please include a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), there are many types without a definition in your code which makes it impossible to compile.

Comment: From the error message, it seems that this error is related to [object safety](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/0255-object-safety.md) - you cannot create a value of `dyn Packet` because `Packet` contains a method with no `&self` parameter (in your case `deserialize_gen`)

Comment: Awesome thanks! That was definitely one of the issues. I read up on object safety and it turns out another issue is that the `Default` trait isn't object safe because it returns self and the compiler can't determine the size for various implementations (and it doesn't have a concrete type)

Comment: Note that if your trait is not object-safe, you can still use trait objects. You can create a helper trait that is object-safe, and provide a blanket implementation of the helper trait for all types that implement the original (non-object-safe) trait. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64840069/1600898) shows how to use the `Hash` trait (non-object-safe because its titular method is generic) to create type-erased behavior through an intermediate object-safe trait.