# Vector of objects sharing a trait with PartialEq dependency

Tags: inheritance, vector, rust, traits

I'm trying to make a `vector` that would store objects of different structs that implement a certain `trait`, however, I really want my trait to be a **supertrait of `Eq`** (and thus `PartialEq`).

[The Book](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch17-02-trait-objects.html#defining-a-trait-for-common-behavior) provides a way to do that with `Vec<Box<dyn Draw>>`, however, the `PartialEq` dependency seems to disallow this approach with [the trait cannot be made into an object](https://doc.rust-lang.org/error-index.html#E0038) error.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64840069/10919379) provides a way to do a similar thing for `HashMap`s. However, this approach seems too verbose for what I am trying to achieve.

What would be the idiomatic way to have a vector for structs implementing such a trait?

Code to reproduce below and on the [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3e5de734545824fe272674ce45868c2f)

```rust
pub trait MyTrait: PartialEq { fn my_func() -> bool; }

pub struct Struct1 { age: i32 }

impl PartialEq<Self> for Struct1 {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool { self.age == other.age }
}

impl MyTrait for Struct1 {
    fn my_func() -> bool { false }
}
pub struct Struct2 { year: i32 }

impl PartialEq<Self> for Struct2 {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool { self.year == other.year }
}

impl MyTrait for Struct2 {
    fn my_func() -> bool { true }
}

fn main() {
    let mut v: Vec<Box<dyn MyTrait>> = Vec::new();
    // v.push(Struct1 { age: 1 });
    // v.push(Struct2 { year: 2 });
}
```

Comment: The way is in the answer you linked. I don't think there's a better way. But why do you want `PartialEq` as a supertrait?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman, I want an easy way to know if two of the instances are equal. Such that I could, for example, search the vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on your actual use case, this may or may not work for you, but from the info in your question and comment, I wouldn't go the trait object route but rather the enum route. Have all the types you want to store as variants on an enum, for example like this:

```
pub trait MyTrait: PartialEq { fn my_func(&self) -> bool; }

pub enum Struct {
    Struct1 {
        age: i32,
    },
    Struct2 {
        year: i32,
    }
}

impl PartialEq<Self> for Struct {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        use Struct::*;
        match (self, other) {
            (Struct1 { age: age1 }, Struct1 { age: age2 }) => age1 == age2,
            (Struct2 { year: year1 }, Struct2 { year: year2 }) => year1 == year2,
            _ => false
        }
    }
}

impl MyTrait for Struct {
    fn my_func(&self) -> bool {
        use Struct::*;
        match self {
            Struct1 { .. } => false,
            Struct2 { .. } => true,
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut v: Vec<Struct> = Vec::new();
    v.push(Struct::Struct1 { age: 1 });
    v.push(Struct::Struct2 { year: 2 });
    assert!(v.contains(&Struct::Struct2 { year: 2 }));
}
```

Feel free to let me know if there are more constraints that would make this approach infeasible.

Comment: I initially wanted to avoid the enums because they would add an extra layer to my objects, for example, every time I create one, I have to wrap it into an enum. But choosing between this and the other solution, this one sounds easier. Also, so far I was unable to write a `wrap` function that would take a template type implementing `MyTrait` and return an enum value.

Comment: @MikhailVlasenko Maybe you should re-evaluate how important being a supertrait of `PartialEq` really is. Most functions that have a `PartialEq` bound have a `_by_key` companion function (or something similar) that let you pass in a custom method of comparison. That may end up being more convenient for you.