# How do I make many different structs that all implement the same trait comparable to each other?

Tags: oop, rust

In Java-lingo, I have an `interface R`, an `interface RT extends R` (where `RT` implements all of `R`) and a bunch of other classes that all implement `RT`.

Transitioning to Rust I ended up with two traits

```
trait R { ... }
trait RT { ... }
```

where `RT` is a "subtrait" of `R`:

```
impl R for X where X: RT { ... }
```

Following that I have a bunch of structs, all of which implement `RT`:

```
struct RV { ... }
impl RT for RV { ... }

struct I { ... }
impl RT for I { ... }

struct U { ... }
impl RT for U { ... }

// ...
```

So far so good.

Now I want all of these structs to be comparable to each other, on the basis that all of them implement `RT`.

In Java I would change `RT` to

```
interface RT extends R, Comparable<RT>
```

and add a default implementation for `equals` and `compareTo`.

In Rust I have no idea if or how this could be approached.

I could say `trait RT: PartialEq`, but that would only make one implementation comparable with itself (`RV == RV`, but not `RV == U`).

My next idea was to add blanket implementations for every struct:

```
impl PartialEq<RV> for X where X: RT
impl PartialEq<I> for X where X: RT
// ...
```

I understand why this isn't allowed, however I'm still stuck with my initial problem.

I can't cast the values for comparison (`RV as RT == U as RT`) because `RT` can't be made into an object.

I could manually implement `PartialEq<T>` for every combination of structs but that would be a lot of duplication.

I considered using a macro to generate all the different implementations, but that feels so much like brute-forcing, that I question the initial design of my program.

How do I make all the different structs comparable to each other?

Comment: "subtrait" would mean `trait RT: R { ... }` (which might also be something you want). You just have a regular trait and a "blanket `impl`"

Comment: You are correct, that's why I put "subtrait" in quotes. Would `trait RT: R` make a difference to the current state of things?

Comment: Not in terms of your actual question, no. I think it can make a difference to what the compiler can deduce about types in certain situations, but I can't think of an example right now.

Comment: In Java, this line of reasoning makes sense because concrete classes implementing your interface can override the default implementation you've provided as necessary. In (stable) Rust, you *cannot* do that. Given this constraint, it doesn't make sense that you could implement equality checks for between any two types simply because they implement your `RT` trait. Usually, the more ideomatic thing to do in Rust is add constraints to your methods something along the lines of `<T where T: RT + PartialEq<T>>`. The exact constraint would depend on your requirements.

Comment: Well, that answers my question, I guess. What do you mean by "stable" exactly. Is there something on the horizon in nightly rust?

Comment: I believe (and I may be wrong) that they're referring to the fact that you can't currently have multiple overlapping implementations of a trait. The [specialization](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/31844) feature, which is currently only on nightly, intends to make it so you can override one impl with a more specific one.

Comment: I believe your question is answered by the answers of [How to test for equality between trait objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25339603/155423). If you disagree, please [edit] your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: If I understand the linked response correctly, it only works with `'static` references, which does not apply to my problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to test for equality between trait objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339603/how-to-test-for-equality-between-trait-objects)

Comment: It is not true that the answers to the linked question require `'static` references, so I have voted to close this one.

Answer (score 2):

That pattern often arises in Java to emulate tagged unions, which are missing from the Java language.  In Rust, unless you are writing a library whose users may need to define new implementations of `RT`, I suspect you’ll be happier with an `enum` instead of a trait object:

```rust
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq)]
enum AnyRT {
    RV(RV),
    I(I),
    U(U),
}

impl RT for AnyRT {
    fn foo(&self, ...) {
        match self {
            AnyRT::RV(rv) => rv.foo(...),
            AnyRT::I(i) => i.foo(...),
            AnyRT::U(u) => u.foo(...),
        }
    }
}
```

Depending on your application, you may then find that you don’t need the `RT` trait and/or the separate `RV`, `I`, `U` structs at all.