# Trait convertion into another trait to use in dyn variable

Tags: rust

I have variable like `let t1: &dyn T1` or `let t1: Box<dyn T1>` or like this from external library. I want to use this variable as another trait. So, i have code

```
fn another_function(let t2: Box<dyn T2>);

let t1: Box<dyn T1> = run_external_function();
another_function(t1);
```

How can I convert a trait in Rust to another trait? For example

```
trait T1{}
trait T2{}
impl T2 for dyn T1{}

let t1: &dyn T1 = ;
let t2: &dyn T2 = t1;
```

I tried it in similar [code](https://rust.godbolt.org/z/dhdr98jTq), but it fails with error

> expected trait `T2`, found trait `T1`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Implement a trait for all types implementing a trait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57274864/implement-a-trait-for-all-types-implementing-a-trait)

Answer (score 2):

Converting a `dyn T1` to a `dyn T2` cannot work. Think about it: `dyn T1` contains the data, but the `dyn T2` will also have to contain the type, that is, the vtable. When will we store it? Usually, it is stored in the reference, but there is no reference here!

One way to make this work is to impl `T2` for `&'_ dyn T1` instead of for `dyn T1`:

```rust
impl T2 for &'_ dyn T1 {}

let t1: &dyn T1 = ...;
let t2: &dyn T2 = &t1;
```

Now the first reference stores the vtable for `T1`, and the second reference stores the vtable for `T2`.

Comment: > Converting a dyn T1 to a dyn T2 cannot work.
I mean, we could convert &dyn T1 into &dyn T2 by additing new vtable and saving old reference on variable.
The compiler gives the same error: https://rust.godbolt.org/z/hd3T8oMoe

Comment: @SuvorovIvan Where we would save the vtable of `T1`?

Comment: If i understand how it works, for example, if we have usual variable (not trait), we create vtable next to it, and keep this variable too, so we have pair (vtable, variable). If we have &dyn T, this is like a pointer, so we create vtable next to it and keep in pair (vtable, pointer_to_some_object). What's wrong?

Comment: @SuvorovIvan The problem is that we need to store _two_ vtables. If I understand you correctly, you want to store a triple: data pointer, `T1`'s vtable and `T2`'s vtable. However, the size of `&dyn T2` is already set to be two `usize`s, not three, and we cannot change it (for example, we may need to pass it into a function that expects it to be two).

Comment: Not, why? We converted variable to dyn T2, it means, we don't need in T1 type anymore. Yes, t2 variable still have vtable for T1, but this vtable is hidden behind ptr. So, i suppose, there will be next approximation: t2 == (T2 vtable, *(T1 vtable, *real_object)). But nested pair is still object, it doesn't matter

Comment: @SuvorovIvan Do you store `T1`'s vtable flatten (in this case I explained why it is impossible) or behind a pointer? If behind a pointer, how does it get there?

Comment: Yes, behind pointer. We don't need mechanism to get it. We converted variable to T2 and we lost all information about T1. It looks like usual variable. let t = T::new(); let t2: &dyn T2 = &t; How can we get T type from t2 variable back? Maybe, I called the question incorrect. We don't extend trait, we exchange trait

Comment: @SuvorovIvan The point is, we do need to keep the vtable for `T1`. Maybe the methods of `T2` needs to call methods of `T1`. The difference between the cases is that in the case you presented `T` is the type only at compile time, but in our case `dyn T1` is a dynamic type that `T2` is implemented for, and thus we need to keep its vtable.

Comment: But for T2, T1 vtable is saved. As for usual variable T, inside trait T2 we use methods of T. Also inside trait T2 we can use methods of dyn T1, why not?

Comment: @SuvorovIvan Because methods of `T` are known statically, but for methods of `dyn T1` we need vtable.

Comment: I don't see a big difference, but this chat is too inconvenient