# How can I test equality to a given boxed object implementing a trait?

Tags: rust

I'm writing a ray-tracer to learn Rust. I've got a `Scene` which contains `Shape`s, shapes that can intersect rays. Minimally, it is akin to:

```
pub trait Shape {
    fn draw(&self);
}

pub struct Plane {}

impl Shape for Plane {
    fn draw(&self) {}
}

pub struct Sphere {}

impl Shape for Sphere {
    fn draw(&self) {}
}

pub struct Scene {
    objects: Vec<Box<dyn Shape>>,
}

fn main() {
    let mut scene = Scene { objects: vec![] };

    let plane1 = Box::new(Plane {});
    let plane2 = Box::new(Plane {});
    let sphere = Box::new(Sphere {});

    scene.objects.push(plane1);
    scene.objects.push(plane2);
    scene.objects.push(sphere);

    for object in scene.objects {
        // I want to test if a given object in the scene is the same as another
        if object == plane2 {}
    }
}
```

Given a shape stored in `Vec<Box<dyn Shape>>` how can I test equality to a given boxed object implementing the Shape trait?

```
error[E0369]: binary operation `==` cannot be applied to type `std::boxed::Box<Shape>`
  --> src/main.rs:34:12
   |
34 |         if object == plane2 {}
   |            ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: an implementation of `std::cmp::PartialEq` might be missing for `std::boxed::Box<Shape>`
```

The test will be done in a `Sphere` or `Plane` member function, testing against `self`.

Comment: Why do you use raw pointer, your question is not clear please do a proper [mcve], `self` is a `Sphere` not a `Box<dyn Intersector>` so why did you expect ?

Comment: Maybe you want `pub fn some_function<T>(&self, intersector: &T) where T: Intersector` ?

Comment: @Shepmaster thanks. Rewritten in MCVE form. I have diffuclty understanding the answers you linked to. Is there a simpler answer with this now clear question?

Comment: Based on your latest changes, [How to test for equality between trait objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25339603/155423) appears to be the duplicate.

Comment: Does `plane1 == plane2`?

Comment: @Shepmaster thanks! Please mark as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, you can convert from a pointer to a `Sphere` to a pointer to an `Intersector` (ie. from a `Sphere*` to an `Intersector*`). It also works with references although this is less idiomatic for C++.

This is exactly the same in Rust, except that in Rust it is more idiomatic to use references rather than raw pointers:

```
impl Scene {
    pub fn some_function(&self, intersector: &Intersector) {
        for object in &self.objects {
            if intersector == object {}
        }
    }
}
```

Note that your original code used `*const Box<dyn Intersector>` which is a pointer to a box containing an `Intersector` and translates roughly to `smart_pointer<Intersector>*` in C++, so your Rust code would be equivalent to passing an `Intersector*` to a function expecting a `smart_pointer<Intersector>*`, which doesn't work in C++ either.

Comment: I'd rather understand how to do it with the boxed object than restart with a different architecture. And in C++, you can easily do if (scene[0].get() == sphere)