# Implement a mutable tree structure using a trait object

Tags: rust, traits

I am trying to implement a tree structure in Rust. My structure is like a JSON object, where properties can be simple values or subtrees of other JSON objects.

For leaves, I have an enum called `ShyScalar`:

```
#[derive(Clone, PartialEq, Debug)]
pub enum ShyScalar {
    Boolean(bool),
    Integer(i64),
    Rational(f64),
    String(String),
    Error(String)
}
```

For nodes, I am trying to create another enum, `ShyValue`. It can be a `Scalar(ShyScalar)` or an `Object` and I am trying to figure out how to implement the `Object` part. The core of it is the trait `ShyAssociation`, which lets me get or set properties using a string name, a crude form of reflection. Here is part of the implementation of the `ShyAssociation` trait, with a sample implementation using a `HashMap`.

```
pub trait ShyAssociation<'a> {
    /// Set the named property to a new value and return the previous value.
    /// If it is not permitted to set this property or it had no value previously, return None.
    fn set(&mut self, property_name: &'a str, property_value: ShyValue) -> Option<ShyValue>;

    /// Get the value of the named property.
    /// If the property has no value or the property does not exist, return None.
    fn get(&self, property_name: &'a str) -> Option<&ShyValue>;

    /// True if is is possible to set the named property. 
    /// This may be true even if the property does not currently have a value.
    fn can_set_property(&self, property_name: &'a str) -> bool;

    /// True if the property currently has a value that can be retrieved, false otherwise.
    fn can_get_property(&self, property_name: &'a str) -> bool;
}

impl<'a> ShyAssociation<'a> for HashMap<&'a str, ShyValue> {
    fn set(&mut self, property_name: &'a str, property_value: ShyValue) -> Option<ShyValue> {
        self.insert(property_name, property_value)
    }

    fn get(&self, property_name: &'a str) -> Option<&ShyValue> {
        HashMap::get(self, property_name)
    }

    fn can_set_property(&self, _property_name: &'a str) -> bool {
        true
    }

    fn can_get_property(&self, property_name: &'a str) -> bool {
        self.contains_key(property_name)
    }
}
```

This worked before the `ShyValue` included the `Object` variant.

I have tried using `Box`, and am investigating `Rc` and `RefCell`, but do not know how to compose things so that I can implement the three essential traits for `Object`: `Clone`, `PartialEq` and `Debug`.

I was able to get `Clone` working if I use the [objekt crate](https://github.com/dtolnay/objekt), which implements ideas from [How to clone a struct storing a boxed trait object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30353462/how-to-clone-a-struct-storing-a-boxed-trait-object).

I cannot figure out how to compose things so as to implement all three traits.

---

The larger problem I am trying to solve is to build the context object (symbol table) for a rules engine. I need to be able to supply arbitrary objects that implement `ShyAssociation` to permit the rules engine to extract values using dot notation and set the results back into the objects. I am trying to get around the fact that Rust does not support reflection.

---

Additional information.

When I use objekt_clonable crate and try to compose with PartialEq and Debug, I get these errors:

> the trait `parser::shy_association::ShyAssociation` cannot be made
>   into an object
>
> the trait `parser::shy_association::ShyAssociation` cannot be made
>   into an object
>
> note: the trait cannot use `Self` as a type parameter in the
>   supertraits or where-clausesrustc(E0038)
>   <::objekt::macros::__internal_clone_trait_object macros>(38, 55): the
>   trait `parser::shy_association::ShyAssociation` cannot be made into an
>   object

Here is some of the code I use:

```
use objekt_clonable::*;
#[clonable]
pub trait ShyAssociation<'a> :  Clone + PartialEq + Debug  {
    /// Set the named property to a new value and return the previous value.
    /// If it is not permitted to set this property or it had no value previously, return None.
    fn set(&mut self, property_name: &'a str, property_value: ShyValue) -> Option<ShyValue>;

    /// Get the value of the named property.
    /// If the property has no value or the property does not exist, return None.
    fn get(&self, property_name: &'a str) -> Option<&ShyValue>;

    /// True if is is possible to set the named property. 
    /// This may be true even if the property does not currently have a value.
    fn can_set_property(&self, property_name: &'a str) -> bool;

    /// True if the property currently has a value that can be retrieved, false otherwise.
    fn can_get_property(&self, property_name: &'a str) -> bool;
}
```

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [How to test for equality between trait objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25339603/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: Also `pub trait ShyAssociation<'a>: Debug {...}`

Comment: I will consult that solution and see if I can compose it with the Clone solution. My problem has not been individually implementing the Traits, it is getting all of them to work together without a compile error.