# Testing iterator over dynamic trait objects

Tags: rust

I have two types `A` and `B` that implement the `Fooable` trait. I have an array of `A`s, and an array of `B`s, and create an iterator over the two arrays, the iterator having Item type `&dyn Fooable`. I want to write a test to confirm that the iterator outputs the correct objects, something like:

```
struct C {
    as_array: [A; 2],
    bs_arry: [B; 2],
}

impl C {
    fn contents_iter(&self) -> FoosIterator {
        FoosIterator {
            a_iter: (&self.as_array).into_iter(),
            b_iter: (&self.bs_arry).into_iter(),
        }
    }
}

struct FoosIterator<'a> {
    a_iter: <&'a [A; 2] as IntoIterator>::IntoIter,
    b_iter: <&'a [B; 2] as IntoIterator>::IntoIter,
}

impl<'a> Iterator for FoosIterator<'a> {
    type Item = &'a dyn Fooable;
    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        match self.a_iter.next() {
            Some(upper_slot) => Some(upper_slot),
            None => self.b_iter.next().map(|x| x as &dyn Fooable),
        }
    }
}

trait Fooable: std::fmt::Debug {
    fn calculate_num(&self) -> i32;
}

#[derive(PartialEq, Debug)]
struct A {
    value: i32,
}

impl Fooable for A {
    fn calculate_num(&self) -> i32 {
        self.value
    }
}

#[derive(PartialEq, Debug)]
struct B {
    value_1: i32,
    value_2: i32,
}

impl Fooable for B {
    fn calculate_num(&self) -> i32 {
        self.value_1 * 5 + self.value_2
    }
}

#[test]
fn test_contents_iter() {
    let c = C {
        as_array: [A { value: 3 }, A { value: 5 }],
        bs_arry: [
            B {
                value_1: 3,
                value_2: 1,
            },
            B {
                value_1: 5,
                value_2: 2,
            },
        ],
    };
    let mut iter = c.contents_iter();
    assert_eq!(
        *iter
            .next()
            .expect("Should have initial element from iterator"),
        A { value: 3 }
    );
    assert_eq!(
        *iter
            .next()
            .expect("Should have second element from iterator"),
        A { value: 5 }
    );
    assert_eq!(
        *iter
            .next()
            .expect("Should have third element from iterator"),
        B {
            value_1: 3,
            value_2: 1
        }
    );
    assert_eq!(
        *iter
            .next()
            .expect("Should have fourth element from iterator"),
        B {
            value_1: 5,
            value_2: 2
        }
    );
}
```

The problem is that objects of type `&dyn Fooable` do not implement the `PartialEq` trait, so cannot be compared for equality:

```
error[E0369]: binary operation `==` cannot be applied to type `dyn Fooable`
  --> src/lib.rs:73:5
   |
73 | /     assert_eq!(
74 | |         *iter
75 | |             .next()
76 | |             .expect("Should have initial element from iterator"),
77 | |         A { value: 3 }
78 | |     );
   | |      ^
   | |      |
   | |______dyn Fooable
   |        A
   |
   = note: an implementation of `std::cmp::PartialEq` might be missing for `dyn Fooable`
   = note: this error originates in a macro outside of the current crate (in Nightly builds, run with -Z external-macro-backtrace for more info)
```

As I understand it (for instance from [How to test for equality between trait objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339603/how-to-test-for-equality-between-trait-objects)) there is no way to implement this trait for a dynamic type. Is there any way to achieve something like the aim here? I suppose one could instead expose some of the data constituting objects of type `A` and `B` in the `Fooable` trait, and use this to check that the objects outputted are the correct ones (in my actual use case the `A`s and `B`s are more complicated than in my toy example above).

Comment: It looks like your question might be answered by the answers of [How to get a reference to a concrete type from a trait object?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33687447/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: In my use case the "create_vector" object does not have a static lifetime, which I believe means that one cannot downcast via Any? I've edited the question accordingly

Comment: *static lifetimes seems unattractive in a language whose calling card is safe, efficient memory management* — this appears to be a non-sequitur. These two things, while related, aren't relevant to each other in this situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the absence of any better ideas, one possible workaround is to make use of the Debug trait for `A`s and `B`s: testing the formatted debugging output for equality is often equivalent to the intended notion of equality between `A`s and `B`s.

```
/* ... */
assert_eq!(
    format!("{:?}", *iter
        .next()
        .expect("Should have initial element from iterator")),
    format("{:?}", A { value: 3 })
);
assert_eq!(
    format!("{:?}", *iter
        .next()
        .expect("Should have second element from iterator")),
    format("{:?}", A { value: 5 })
);
assert_eq!(
    format!("{:?}", *iter
        .next()
        .expect("Should have third element from iterator")),
    format("{:?}",         
    B {
        value_1: 3,
        value_2: 1
    })
);
assert_eq!(
    format!("{:?}", *iter
        .next()
        .expect("Should have third element from iterator")),
    format("{:?}",         
    B {
        value_1: 5,
        value_2: 2
    })
);
```