# Making a mock implementation record any number of arguments

Tags: unit-testing, rust, mocking

### Context & my attempts

I am trying to unit-test a function, and I want to make sure it calls the correct API endpoint with the correct arguments.

My first idea was to make the function I wanted to test accept the API as a trait object. This would allow me to mock it. I also had to pass mutable references, because the mock should record information about how it was called. Below you see a simplified representation of my code structure:

```rust
trait API {
    fn func_a(&mut self, arg1: i32, arg2: String);
}

// prod trait implementation

#[allow(dead_code)]
fn business_logic(api: &mut dyn API) {
    api.func_a(42, String::from("mytrousersareblue"));
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use super::*;

    #[derive(Default)]
    struct Mock<A, B> {
        args: (A, B),
    }
    impl API for Mock<i32, String> {
        fn func_a(&mut self, arg1: i32, arg2: String) {
            self.args = (arg1, arg2);
        }
    }

    #[test]
    fn business_logic_performs_correct_calls() {
        let mut mock: Mock<i32, String> = Default::default();
        business_logic(&mut mock);
        assert_eq!(mock.args.0, 42);
        assert_eq!(mock.args.1, String::from("mytrousersareblue"));
    }
}
```

This has various downsides, mainly that I have to make separate `Mock` structs for functions with zero, one, two, three, and more parameters.

So another idea that came to my mind was to implement the `Mock` struct as follows:

```rust
struct Mock<'a> {
    args: Vec<&'a dyn Eq>,
}
```

This would allow me to record as many arguments as I want. However the compiler complains that ***the trait `std::cmp::Eq` cannot be made into an object***.

I cannot use `std::any::Any`, because I still need to be able to determine equality in the `assert_eq` statements.

Maybe I am taking a completely wrong path here. I do have quite some trouble with the Rust mindset, coming from a Java background...

### Summary / TLDR

I want to have a mock-implementation of the API, which records all arguments it was called with, that can later be compared against expected values.

If I'm correct, then I'll need a way to make a struct store any number of objects, which all extend at least `Eq`. However, if there's a nicer solution: I'm open.

Comment: You should probably take a look at the [mockall](https://crates.io/crates/mockall/) crate. This uses macros to derive mocks for a particular trait.

Comment: Yup, thanks! That turned out to be the solution for my case. However, I found an article showing how to tackle this problem without packages and without macros. As soon as I understand it enough to explain it, I'll post an answer to it.
The blog post is the following: https://dev.to/magnusstrale/rust-trait-objects-in-a-vector-non-trivial-4co5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found two solutions:

### The practical one:

Use the [mockall](https://crates.io/crates/mockall/) crate (thanks @Richard Matheson for the recommendation). Seriously, don't try to re-implement mocking yourself. The mockall crates does it using macros, and it is pure magic. But it works.

### The nightmare:

I don't recommend using this answer, but it is helpful to know as a design concept.

The way to solve this problem, is to declare a trait implementing `Any` and defining the following functions:

```rust
trait Arg: Any {
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any;
    fn equals_arg(&self, _: &dyn Any) -> bool;
}
```

Then you implement this trait for as many structs as possible:

```rust
impl<S: 'static + PartialEq> Arg for S {
    fn as_any(&self) -> &dyn Any {
        self
    }

    fn equals_arg(&self, other: &dyn Arg) -> bool {
        other
            .as_any()
            .downcast_ref::<S>()
            .map_or(false, |a| self == a)
    }
}
```

Implementing the `as_any` function is straightforward. The `equals_arg` function is trickier. We compare these two references by first trying to downcast the `other` object to the type of `self`. If that fails, we immediately return `false`. If it succeeds, we compare them using the `==` operator, made available because both implement the `PartialEq` trait.

We can now store an array of `dyn Arg` elements and compare them using `equals_arg`. See [the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=8167c164b5939aaf3c68b3b0201d82d8) for an example implementation. (In the playground I changed the API interface to accept `&'static` types. This could certainly be improved, but I am a beginner concerning lifetimes.)

### References

- https://dev.to/magnusstrale/rust-trait-objects-in-a-vector-non-trivial-4co5
- [How to test for equality between trait objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25339603/how-to-test-for-equality-between-trait-objects)