# Correct implementation of Debug for dyn trait that uses pointers

Tags: rust

I want to be able to compare two structs, when the structs contain a reference to a trait inside them. I only care about knowing that the two references are to the same memory location. My code compiles, runs, and shows that the two references are *not* equal. I expected them to be equal, so I have a bug. But my Debug impl shows that they *are* equal, so I'm confused.

I haven't been able to make a self-contained repo of my bug, but I can reproduce my `Debug` problem:

```rust
#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
struct Intersection<'a> {
    intersected: &'a dyn Intersectable,
}

trait Intersectable {}
impl<'a> core::fmt::Debug for dyn Intersectable + 'a {
    fn fmt(&self, f: &mut std::fmt::Formatter<'_>) -> std::fmt::Result {
        write!(f, "Intersectable{{{:?}}}", core::ptr::addr_of!(self))
    }
}
impl<'a> PartialEq for dyn Intersectable + 'a {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        std::ptr::eq(self, other)
    }
}

#[derive(Debug, PartialEq)]
struct Sphere {}
impl Intersectable for Sphere {}

#[test]
fn comparison_bug() {
    let sphere = Sphere{};
    let other = Sphere{};
    let i = Intersection{ intersected: &sphere };

    assert_eq!(i.intersected, &sphere as &dyn Intersectable);
    assert_eq!(i.intersected, &other as &dyn Intersectable);
}
```

In the test, the assertion `assert_eq!(i.intersected, &other as &dyn Intersectable);` fails. This is correct -- I'm looking at two different instances of a `Sphere` struct, so the definitely *are not equal*.

The problem is that the message printed by `assert_eq!` says

```
assertion failed: `(left == right)`
  left: `Intersectable{0x7faebfa72188}`,
 right: `Intersectable{0x7faebfa72188}`
```

This is no good. I'm trying to print the address of each reference, so left and right should be different addresses (as the test correctly determined!). Why is my `Debug` printing the same address for both?

I also tried making my impl of `PartialEq` into `addr_of!(self) == addr_of(other)` and it behaves exactly the same (the test fails correctly but the Debug message appears to show that they are the same address).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are currently doing is getting a pointer *to the reference*; you are getting `addr_of!(self)` but `self` is a reference. This would be a function local variable and therefore the address can be the same as another invocation. Instead, you want the address of what `self` refers to, use `*self`:

```
write!(f, "Intersectable{{{:?}}}", core::ptr::addr_of!(*self))
```

You can avoid using `addr_of!` though by using the pointer format specifier, `"{:p}"`, instead:

```
write!(f, "Intersectable{{{self:p}}}")
```

---

However, your test is flawed because `Sphere` is a [zero-sized type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/beta/nomicon/exotic-sizes.html#zero-sized-types-zsts) (ZST). This means it can take up no memory and therefore multiple ZSTs can occupy the same memory address. When I ran your test in `--release` mode, it gave `sphere` and `other` the same address and therefore your test succeeds when you're expecting it not to.

If `Sphere` is not actually intended to be a ZST (and just an artifact of minimization), then there's not much to worry about, but it is something to keep in mind when considering pointer equality.

As an additional note: you should avoid [`std::ptr::eq`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ptr/fn.eq.html) for comparing `dyn Intersectable`:

> When comparing wide pointers, both the address and the metadata are tested for equality. However, note that comparing trait object pointers (`*const dyn Trait`) is unreliable: pointers to values of the same underlying type can compare inequal (because vtables are duplicated in multiple codegen units), and pointers to values of *different* underlying type can compare equal (since identical vtables can be deduplicated within a codegen unit).

Comment: That's a really helpful explanation. And thanks for the additional notes. (Sphere is not a ZST in my actual code, but it's neat that Rust will collapse them when it can!) I'll have to re-think what to do with my PartialEq... I don't really want to jump through Any like https://stackoverflow.com/a/25359060/1220269

Comment: @NathanielWaisbrot You can cast the pointer to `*const ()` (`self as *const Self as *const () == other as *const Self as *const ()`) and then it'll discard the vtable.